# Characterization of non solvable groups in terms of normal series.

Tags: finite-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

I have encountered the following statement which I cannot prove:

> A finite group $G$ is not solvable if and only if there is a NORMAL series with
>
> $$ 1\lhd H \lhd N \lhd G $$
>
> such that [$N/H$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310884/characterization-of-non-solvable-groups?r=SearchResults#comment4756573_2310884) is a nonabelian simple group or product of isomorphic nonabelian simple groups.

I guess by a normal series is meant the usual, that any term of the series is normal in the whole group $G$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $H/N$ should be $N/H$. I'm not allowed to do this as an edit as it involves too few characters.

Comment: Which direction of the proof do you have problems with? In either case, since $G$ is finite, you can use the method of infinite descent (i.e. assume that $G$ is a counterexample of minimal order).